# Terser syntax for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only if one condition is true?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I know I can do something like

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    exampleColumn1 = IF (exampleCondition = 1, VALUES(exampleColumn1), exampleColumn1),
    exampleColumn2 = IF (exampleCondition = 1, VALUES(exampleColumn2), exampleColumn2),
    exampleColumn3 = IF (exampleCondition = 1, VALUES(exampleColumn3), exampleColumn3),
    # Etc etc
```

But since I'm doing the exact same condition check every time, surely there's a terser way to write this?  It would be especially nice in those cases where the condition is a bit longer to write out.

From what I've read, it seems possible if I wrote a function for this, but can I do it in a plain old query?

Comment: Please show us the entire query.

Comment: It’s meant more as a general question for any INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... format query, where every column in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE has the exact same IF condition applied in order to determine whether to update the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell: no. The `on duplicate key` syntax does not support any form of filtering (`where` condition or the-like).

If you condition is lengthy, however, one trick is to make use of a user variable to hold its return value, that you can reuse in the following assignments:

```
on duplicate key update
    exampleColumn1 = if(@do_update := (exampleCondition = 1), values(exampleColumn1), exampleColumn1),
    exampleColumn2 = if(@do_update, values(exampleColumn2), exampleColumn2),
    exampleColumn3 = if(@do_update, values(exampleColumn3), exampleColumn3)
```

Comment: I remember user variables having unexpected behavior at times if they were initialized and used in the same statement.  Would that not be a possible problem here?

Comment: @0xN0: yes that's true in `select` statements, where the order of evaluation of columns is undefined, but not in `update`s, that are evaluated from left to right, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). `UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;` : *The second assignment in the statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.*

Comment: Ahhhhh I see.  Thanks!